# model.BelongsTo is not a funtion

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I want to implement sequlize migration into node.js project

I have the models/index.js file

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.js')[env];
const db = {};

/* Custom handler for reading current working directory */
const models = process.cwd() +'/models'  || __dirname + "models" ;


let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
 
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.username,
    config.password,
    config,
  );

  try {
    sequelize.authenticate();
   console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
 } catch (error) {
   console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
 }
}
/* fs.readdirSync(__dirname) */
fs.readdirSync(models)
  .filter(file => {
    return (
      file.indexOf('.') !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === '.js'
    );
  })
  .forEach(file => {
   
    const model = require(path.join(models, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes)
      
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

and I have models files that just has the standerd sequlize model
code like the follows
models/contract.js

```js
//var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const contract =  sequelize.define(
    'contract',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        validate: {
          isUUID: 4
        },
        primaryKey: true
      },
      start_date: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false
      },
      end_date: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false
      },
    },
    );

   
  contract.associate = function (models) {
    // associations can be defined here

  contract.BelongsTo(models.customer
    //   , 
      
    //   {
    //   as: {
    //     singular: 'customer',
    //     plural: 'customers'
    //   },

    // }
    );
contract.HasMany(models.taskContract
      , {
      // as: {
      //   singular: 'taskContract',
      //   plural: 'taskContracts'
      // },
      foreignKey: {
        name: "contract_id",
        allowNull: false
      }
    })
  };
  return contract;
};
```

and a simple express server

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const db = require('./models/index')

require('dotenv').config();
db.sequelize.sync()


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

I keep getting that the model.association is not a function.

I think it has something to do with sequelize object instanciation
but I am creating new instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with Index.js.

```html
'use strict';

    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');
    const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    const basename = path.basename(__filename);
    const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
    const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
    const db = {};

    let sequelize;
    if (config.use_env_variable) {
      sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
    } else {
      sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
    }

    fs
      .readdirSync(__dirname)
      .filter(file => {
        return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
      })
      .forEach(file => {
        const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
        db[model.name] = model;
      });

    Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
      if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
      }
    });

    db.sequelize = sequelize;
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

    module.exports = db;
```

Contract.js

```html
const Contract =  sequelize.define(
    'contract',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        validate: {
          isUUID: 4
        },
        primaryKey: true
      },
      start_date: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false
      },
      end_date: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false
      },
    },
    );

   
  Contract.associate = function (models) {
    // associations can be defined here

  Contract.BelongsTo(models.customer);
  Contract.HasMany(models.TaskContract, {
       foreignKey: {
        name: "contract_id",
        allowNull: false
      }
    })
  };
  return Contract;
```

Please make sure you have add sequelize in app.js root file.